# JMS - Redelivery flow in a queue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, message-queue, message-driven-bean

**Configuration**

I´m using EJB 3 in OC4J 10.1.3.x

**The problem**

I create a queue producer with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE orientation, like:

```
    queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false,
            Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);

    ObjectMessage objMessage = queueSession.createObjectMessage();
    Mail data = new Mail();
    data.setMessage("Some random message.");
    objMessage.setObject(data);
    queueSender.send(objMessage);
```

What I understand of it is that the consumer should handle the ack of the message, in other words, if the consumer **DO NOT** call the `message.acknowledge()` method, so the message should be redelivery. Is it right?

What is happen is, when my MDB just read the message (by the listener `onMessage`) that message just get off from the queue (independent if I call or not the `message.acknowledge()` method).

```
   public void onMessage(Message message) {
            try {
                if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                    ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
                    Mail mail = (Mail) objectMessage.getObject();
                    System.out.println(mail.getMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error");
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
            }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did lots of research about it and I found that the container usually ignores the client control on session creation. In this case: `queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);` So, if you need to handle message process in a MDB with acknowledge or not you need to work with an EJB transaction.